# Icons not shown using thymeleaf and bootstrap 4

Tags: icons, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm trying to make a simple nav with a couple of links and icons, but if I add thymeleaf th:text the icons are not showed. This code works ok, it shows the icon correctly.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Save</a>
            <a href="#"> <i class="icon-eye"></i>Eye</a>
            <a href="#">Another link</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I add th:text from my resources:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Save</a>
            <a href="#" th:text="#{save}"> <i class="icon-eye"></i>Eye</a>
            <a href="#">Another link</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The icon is not showed any more.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted the answer on behalf of the question author)*.

Solution from Thymeleaf forum:

Structure it like this instead:

```
<a href="#"><span th:text="#{save}" /> <i class="icon-eye"></i>Eye</a>
```

`th:text` overwrites everything in tags beneath it, so you need an additional tag.

Answer (score 1):

That don't work, you must make to do with span tag and in this tag put th:text 
try with this:

```
<a href="#"> <i class="icon-eye"></i> <span th:text="#{save}">save</span>Eye</a>
```